# Chaining addExpressionAttributeToSelect calls

Tags: filter, sql, collection-filtering

Currently my `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` method has nested expressions and I would like to make it more readable by splitting it into 2 or more `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` calls.

Is it possible to use the output of `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` call as a parameter for another `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` call, or is there an alternative way to get the same result?

This is my current expression:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()  
->addAttributeToSelect(*)  
->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name_lcase',"IF(SUBSTRING({{name}},4,1) REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+',LOWER(TRIM({{name}})),CONCAT(SUBSTRING(LOWER(TRIM({{name}})),1,3),SUBSTRING({{name}},5)))", 'name')  
->addAttributeToFilter('name_lcase', array('like' => $some_string));
```

And here is the pseudo code for the simpler split version:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()  
->addAttributeToSelect(*)
->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name_cleaned',"IF(SUBSTRING({{name}},4,1) REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+',{{name}},CONCAT(SUBSTRING({{name}},1,3),SUBSTRING({{name}},5)))", 'name')
->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name_lcase','LOWER(TRIM({{name_cleaned}}))', 'name_cleaned')
->addAttributeToFilter('name_lcase', array('like' => $some_string));
```